# iphone how to localize only particular parts of app

Tags: iphone, localization, uitableview, plist

i'm making a korean/english app, so naturally i would need both english and korean displayed on the same tableview cell at the same time. i've considered specifying an element in the plist to be a particular language... but how would i write in korean characters?

i have a dreadful feeling there will be much to custom code for this without apple's wonderful documentation. thanks for any guidance in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy monkey. Turns out I thought it was way more difficult than it is, and I skipped even testing the most basic ways of doing it. All you have to do is basically copy and paste the foreign characters into the plist... That's it. Nothing else. Face in hand and lesson learnt.